# How does SVG image pixel size get calculated

Tags: css, svg

If you check the Stackoverflow logo, you will find it is an `<a>` element with a SVG image as a background.

```
#hlogo a {
    text-indent: -999em;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url("img/sprites.png?v=c4222387135a");
    background-image: url("img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c"),none;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

When using developer tool in Chrome to check the SVG image, it said the image size is 240 * 500.

The size of `<a>` element is 200 * 50 px.

So how does 240 * 500 px, size of SVG image, get calculated?

We both know SVG is a scalable image, vector based, so it should not have a fixed pixel size anyway.

Based on current element context, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

I find the answer.

Because it is mentioned in the SVG definition.

width="240px" height="500px"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="240px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 240 500" enable-background="new 0 0 240 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2_1_">
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it says that it is 250 x 500 is because the svg contains more than just the Stack Overflow logo. See image below.

[image]

It looks like it is setup like a sprite sheet. Which is why there is a height difference when you look at the height of the logo.

The size should be based of the initial size of the vector when it was created. Since it would have to have a default size when it was created, otherwise an `x` and `y` coordinate value would have no meaning without defined dimensions.

So when this svg was created, it was created with the dimensions `250 x 500` and the vectors are based off of those dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. My question is how does 240 * 500 get calculated? Shouldn't SVG size be undetermined?

Comment: From my understanding, the size should be based of the initial size of the vector when it was created. Since it would have to have a default size when it was created, otherwise an `x` and `y` coordinate value would have no meaning without defined dimensions. Updated Answer.

Comment: I think SVG files include a 'dpi' (dots per inch) property, or something similar. This would be used to determine how the vector graphics are scaled to bitmap resolutions.